# How can I use string interpolation in the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, string-interpolation

I learned that using $"" and {} allows me to handle strings more freely. And I wanted to use them in the inspector but if I type $"Hi" in the inspector it just recognizes the $ and " as normal characters.

Comment: Please elaborate what you expect out of $"Hi".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work around that I came up with is to:

1. Serialize a text area that you want to type in;
2. Write a quick method that parses that string by using `myString.Replace("{myNumber}", $"{myNumber}")`;
3. Make sure the method that you write has a parameter for the number that you want to pass into it, i.e.
   `private string Parse(string myString, int myNumber)` OR if you want to make a reusable method you can add parameters with a default argument e.g.
   `private string Parse(string myString, int myNumber = 0, string name = null)`;
4. Now store the parsed string from the method in a variable, and feed that variable into your HUD instead.

Answer (score 3):

of course it does. $"" and {} you are talking about are c# code syntax. The inspector is a GUI, it doesn't consider your input as such, it doesn't interpret it, it considers it to be plain text.

So the short answer to your actual question "how can i?" is "you can not"... it's not meant for that.

Why don't you elaborate what you're trying to achive as suggested by CodingYoshi, so that maybe we can help you achive your end-goal without using string interpolation in the inspector

Comment: I want to show integer variable that keeps changing. I want to tell the player the attack damage of an enemy but I don't want to change the text manually every time I change the attack value. Also, I want it to be in the inspector because the text should be different from other enemies that share the same script.

Comment: if you want to change the integer "attack" value for one instance/gameobject, and have some text change automatically as well, serialize the integer value so that you can change it in the editor (as an int) and do the text adaptation programmatically (ie in the Update function of some monobehaviour on that gameobject, read the attack value and write it as a string into what ever text field)

Comment: Basically use the $"" and {} inside a script that is attached to the game object and has access to the attack value and the text you want to display the value in